# Show in a UML class diagram that an aggregation is a subset of another

Tags: uml, ocl

I have a class diagram with the following two aggregations:

[image: Aggregations constraint problem]

`contentCategories` is a dynamic array of categories, `currentCategory` is always an element of that array, but is maintained as a distinct member variable. I need to show the constraint that it is always an element of `contentCategories` in OCL. Have I done this correctly? If not, what would be the correct way to do it?

Thank you all for your help in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you can keep an index like, CurrentCategoryIndex, instead of keeping an object that already exists in the array.

Comment: Having the pointer to the object directly allows me to save the time needed for indexing into the array all the time, although this would be negligible given the number of accesses to the object in my case. Anyway, there is no way I can update this any more. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your idea is right. I would write the constraint in a comment, though, and w/o a dashed line

EDIT: sorry, in order to be "academically sound" your OCL constraint should also be correct even if there is no `currentCategory`. That means, the constraint'd better read

```
not currentCategory==null implies contentCategories -> includes(currentCategory)
```